# Difficulty in understanding the error in python

Tags: python, string

I wrote a piece of code in python that reads a string, split it into 2 parts,the first being a string again and the second being an integer.
For example

```
ABDKEK 1255443
```

The code is as follows:

```
   L=raw_input()
   ls=L.split()
   num=int(ls[1])
   L=ls[0]
   len=len(L)
```

and it gives the following error

```
     len=len(L) 
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I make the following change in the code:

```
 length=len(L)
```

and it works.

Can anyone explain what does the error `'int' object is not callable` mean??

Comment: Don't use `len` as a variable name.  If you do, you'll no longer be able to access the builtin function named `len`.  Note that you'll get the same error from, e.g., `3(2)`.  An int cannot be called.

Comment: Yeah..got it..I had also declared the variable len=0 at the beginning. When I removed it, even len=len(L) works, but then if I try to use len(L) one more time, it gives an error, coz now len is a variable and no longer a built in function. Thanks!!

Comment: Yup, you got it!  Good work :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`len` is a function name which is already defined and should not be use as a variable. Try some other name instead.

Comment: Thanks.... but I was asking the interpretation of the error..
as in..why the word 'int' was used.